# Running maven project through Command line

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to running maven java project by command line but i am failed after running two commands and created jar file but when i am going to run this jar file it is showing the error that no manifest attribute but i have added the code into pom.xml

```
<!-- this goes within <build> -->
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <!-- here we specify that we want to use the main method within the App class -->
                    <mainClass>com.sohamkamani.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```